# RxJava 3.0.0 crashes a default Empty Activity project?

Tags: android, exception, rx-java

I create a new project in Android Studio 3.6 with default Empty Activity.

By just adding this to my gradle, sync and compile,

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0"
```

The example app fail to even start, and crash as below

```
2020-03-09 21:47:15.448 12193-12193/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elyeproj.myapplication, PID: 12193
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.elyeproj.myapplication/com.elyeproj.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.elyeproj.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.elyeproj.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.elyeproj.myapplication-DiXzq-aNWvgVfrGsWCptJQ==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 8
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                ... 6 more
```

Is this expected (i.e. I miss something), or is it a bug?

Note, adding `implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.18"` compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Android Studio 4.0 or newer (and more importantly, AGP 4.0 or newer) to use RxJava3 in Android projects, because that is what adds the new desugaring capabilities that RxJava3 relies on.